# Angular2 RxJS 5.01 upgrade TimeoutSubscriber error

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

When I upgrade RxJS from 5.0.0-rc.4 to 5.0.1 my HTTP unit tests fail with ..

> TimeoutSubscriber

The code works with 5.0.0-rc.4

This is the failing code. Any ideas appreciated.

```js
  private getHttpStream$(emit: any, url: string, httpResponseMapCallback: any, method: string) {
    return this.http[method](url, emit, this.options)
      .timeout(Config.http.timeout, new Error('timeout'))

      .map((response: any) => {
        if (response.status && !response.status.toString().startsWith(2)) {
          return response;
        }
        // within the callback, emit provides access to the data emitted
        return httpResponseMapCallback({emit, response});
      })

      .catch((err: any) => {
        // Different code flow in real code v unit test code
        /* istanbul ignore next */
        if (err.status && err.statusText) {
          return Observable.from([err]);
        }

        return Observable.from([err.message]);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overload of `.timeout(timeout, customErr, scheduler)` with a custom error [has been removed](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2257). It was [one of the last changes](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs-core-notes/blob/master/2016-12/december-05.md) going from beta/rc to final release

Change your code to this:

```
return this.http[method](url, emit, this.options)
  .timeout(Config.http.timeout)
```

or if you need a custom error:

```
return this.http[method](url, emit, this.options)
  .timeout(Config.http.timeout)
  .catch(err => err instanceof Rx.TimeoutError ? Rx.Observable.throw(new MyCustomError()) : Rx.Observable.throw(err))
```

Comment: I do apologise, I havent had a chance to test this. I am sure you are right and will accept this answer as soon as I can. I never fail to accept an answer so expect +15 your way soon. thx